# How to set an x,y plot in R with type data before/after where each point also shows the standard deviations?

Tags: r, plot, settings, boxplot

I need to represent the variation before/after a series of social network metrics. The idea is that each point is composed of x-coordinates, y-coordinates where they are the average values of a type of social actor, and the lines represent the standard deviations.

For example: for the moment "before" we have 4 social actors of the type "public institution", and for the moment "after" 6 actors (some are the same, and others new but that doesn't matter because I'm trying to describe from the structure and not from the nodes). From that sample, the averages and the deviation come out, and with the graph what I seek to compare is those who "increase" or "decrease" in different metrics.

Currently my database looks like this (maybe it's advisable to change it, but I think it can be processed this way).

```
    time category    code     Clossenness
    1         PI     PI1          0,658
    1         PI     PI2          0,568
    1         PI     PI3          0,581
    1         PI     PI4          0,595
    1         PI     PI5          0,556
    1         PrI    PrI1         0,658
    1         PrI    PrI2         0,543
    1         NGO's  NGO1         0,568
    1         NGO's  NGO2         0,581
    2         PI     PI1          0,611
    2         PI     PI6          0,600
    2         PI     PI7          0,485
    2         PI     PI8          0,569
    2         PI     PI9          0,579
    2         PI     PI10         0,635
    2         PI     PI11         0,623
    2         PI     PI12         0,623
    2         PI     PI13         0,673
    2         PrI    PrI1         0,673
    2         PrI    PrI3         0,600
    2         NGO's  NGO1         0,750
    2         NGO's  NGO3         0,508
    2         NGO's  NGO4         0,524

structure(list(structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), timecategory = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NGO's", "PI", "PrI"), class = "factor"), 
    code = structure(c(5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 18L, 20L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L), .Label = c("NGO1", "NGO2", "NGO3", "NGO4", "PI1", 
    "PI10", "PI11", "PI12", "PI13", "PI2", "PI3", "PI4", "PI5", 
    "PI6", "PI7", "PI8", "PI9", "PrI1", "PrI2", "PrI3"), class = "factor"), 
    Clossenness = structure(c(15L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 
    6L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 11L, 
    17L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0,485", "0,508", "0,524", "0,543", 
    "0,556", "0,568", "0,569", "0,579", "0,581", "0,595", "0,600", 
    "0,611", "0,623", "0,635", "0,658", "0,673", "0,750"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("", 
"time category", "code", "Clossenness"), row.names = c(NA, -23L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The boxplot represent in a descriptive way the information I need, but it becomes more difficult to compare the changes before / after because you have to look at the boxplot in pairs. Then I find it more appropriate to use the other graph I propose. The difficulty is that I don't know a direct way to make that graph with the same information.

Expected outcome
https://ibb.co/WsrDN7D
Actual outcome
https://ibb.co/M6QWXLv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the function `group_by()` and `summarise()`, you can calculate the mean of each category per each time, and with the function `spread()`, you can regroup these 2 values on the same row:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  time        = rep(c('before', 'after'), each = 8), 
  category    = rep(rep(c('PI', 'NGO'), each = 4), times = 2),
  clossenness = rnorm(16, .6, .1) 
) %>% 

  group_by(time, category) %>% 
  summarise(mean_clos = mean(clossenness)) %>% 

  spread(key = time, value = mean_clos)

  category after before
  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 NGO      0.630  0.595
2 PI       0.573  0.659
```

Then, you can plot the point(before, after) with the function `geom_label()` or `geom_point()`, and compare it to the identity line to see if it increase or decrease.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = before, y = after)) +
  #geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = category)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  xlim(c(.5, .7)) + ylim(c(.5, .7))
```

[image]

In this example, NGO increased, whereas PI decreased.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to arrive at a similar procedure during the course of the afternoon. Your observations have helped me to simplify some of the code. In addition, I have used the following to add the deviations in each of the points. 

`gob3 <- gob2 %>% group_by(time, category, variable) %>% summarise(
    Mean = mean(value, na.rm = T),
    SD = sd(value, na.rm = T)) %>% na.omit()

gob3$lower <- gob3$Mean - gob3$SD
gob3$upper <- gob3$Mean + gob3$SD

gob4 <- data.frame(gob3[gob3$time==1,],gob3[gob3$time==2,])`

Comment: `# grafico
gob4 %>% names
G <- ggplot(gob4, aes(x=Mean, y=Mean.1, col=category))+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower.1, ymax=upper.1))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lower, xmax=upper))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=category), size=1.4)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Dark2')+
  facet_wrap(.~variable, scales = 'free')+theme_test()+
  labs(x='Initial', y='Final')+theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
                                     legend.title = element_blank())`